# Grids with store and viewmodel in Extjs-5.1.2

Tags: extjs, viewmodel, store, extjs5

I'm just getting started with ExtJS and am looking to create a grid which will populate based on data it will receive from the server as a json.  I'm having trouble understanding the architecture and how to separate information to correctly display on the grid view, since it seems much more complex and involved than if I were working in something like vanilla Javascript.

I currently have it working when the data has been hardcoded into the view here:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
requires: [
    'MyApp.view.main.MainController',
    'MyApp.view.main.MainModel',

    'Ext.panel.Panel',
    'Ext.grid.Panel'
    ],

    /*
    ...Other containers and panels here
    */

    xtype: 'grid',

            width: '99%',
            flex: 1,

            store: {
                fields:['name', 'email', 'address', 'hobby', 'notes'],
                data:[
                    { name: 'Rate',  email: "rate@example.com",
                      address: "382 Kilmanjaro", hobby: "tennis", notes: "Lorem ipsum dolor.."},
                    { name: 'Jimjam',  email: "jim@example.com",
                      address: "889 McKinley", hobby: "none"}
                ],
                proxy: {
                    type: 'memory'
                }
            },
            columns: [
                { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
                { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email'},
                { text: 'address', dataIndex: 'address' },
                { text: 'hobby', dataIndex: 'hobby'},
                { text: 'Notes', dataIndex: 'notes', flex: 1, cellWrap: true}
            ]
        }]
```

But I'd like to move the store and data out of the view, and ideally read from a json file (and later a GET request).  Other questions I've seen have had a bunch of different methods to approach this but I find them all rather confusing and none seem to work for me, especially with different versions (I'm using ExtJS 5.1.2).

I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction as to where to place my store and data and how to bind it correctly to the view.  I think my main issues lie with usage of the associated Controller.js, Model.js, and Store.js files, and what kind of information goes in them.

Comment: Have you seen the ExtJS examples? Really useful http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#all in particular you can check this grid example http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#xml-grid loads data from xml file but could be also json.

Comment: I had read them but was having trouble understanding the architecture and how to set up files correctly.  I'd been trying to avoid separating too much or writing javascript functions since I was just testing and getting started, but it looks like that's exactly what I had to do once I understood the underlying Model/Store/View!  I've gotten it working and posted my working solution to my problem!  Thanks for pointing me towards the XML grid, it really helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just updating that I got it working!  I checked out the kitchen sink examples and old documentation from ExtJS4 to understand how the architecture worked.

My main issue was being new to ExtJS and attempting to create something while learning it at the same time, so I hope any other newbies can wrap their heads around this!

The basic idea is that there is a Model, Store, and View, and I've understood it as a Model being a class, a Store being a Collection of those objects, and the view being a display.  A Store depends on a Model, and a View (at least, the grid I was building) depends on a Store.  I tried to avoid separating too many views, writing javascript functions and overriding initComponent, but this was exactly what I had to do to get it working.

So I've written architecture like this:

model/Person.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Person', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields:['name', 'email', 'address', 'hobby', 'notes'],
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'data/UserResponse.json',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'results',
    }
}
```

store/Persons.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Persons', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    /*Model for the store*/
    requires: 'MyApp.model.Person',
    model: 'MyApp.model.Person'
});
```

view/main/Main.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    requires: [

        'Ext.panel.Panel',
        'Ext.grid.Panel',
        'MyApp.view.main.PersonGrid'
    ],

    xtype: 'container',

    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'main'
    },
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'center'
    },
    width: '100%',
    items:
    [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        flex: 1,
        border: false,
        width: '98%',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items:
        [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            height: 30,
            margin: '5 5 1 5',
            flex: 1,
            width: '98%',
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'center'
            },
            title: 'Users - USA',
            collapsible: true,
            items: [
            {
               xtype: 'person-grid',
               rootVisible: true,
               store: 'Persons'
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

view/main/PersonGrid.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.PersonGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.person-grid',

    xtype: 'grid',

    width: '99%',
    flex: 1,

    columns: [
            { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
            { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email'},
            { text: 'address', dataIndex: 'address' },
            { text: 'hobby', dataIndex: 'hobby'},
            { text: 'Notes', dataIndex: 'notes', flex: 1, cellWrap: true}
    ],

    initComponent: function() {
    //initComponent taken from http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#xml-grid
      var me = this;

      this.callParent();
      this.on('afterlayout', this.loadStore, this, {
        delay: 1,
        single: true
      });
    },

    loadStore: function() {
      this.getStore().load();
    }
});
```

data/UserResponse.json:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "results":[
                { name: 'Rate',  email: "rate@example.com",
                  address: "382 Kilmanjaro", hobby: "tennis", notes: "Lorem ipsum dolor.."},
                { name: 'Jimjam',  email: "jim@example.com",
                  address: "889 McKinley", hobby: "none"}
            ]
}
```

app/Application.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    models: ['Person'],
    stores: ['Persons'],
    launch: function () {
        // TODO - Launch the application
    }
});
```

The main difference from what I was attempting before was to separate the grid into its own view, and edit the initComponent function here to load the store (which I wasn't doing earlier)!  Earlier, I had the grid and its configurations nested within the items{} array of other components and trying to autoLoad the store, or utilize storeId and other methods of binding store to grid.

The above architecture works perfectly for me, and I am able to read data from my json file and mock responses from server! :)

Comment: Additionally, by using the `autoLoad: true` configuration when creating the 'person-grid' view, the passed store is loaded automatically, removing the need for defining the initComponent function at all!